# Setting start point of default-scrollbar in css

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have a area which is scrollable and I want to set start/end point of default scrollbar. How can I implement it in css? Is it possible to give to scrollbar a little bit margin?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ScrollContent" style="overflow-y: scroll;">
    <div class="overflow" style="height: 250px;">
      <div>Content</div>
      <div>Content</div>
      <div>Content</div>
      <div>Content</div>
      <div>Content</div>
      <div>Content</div>
      <div>Content</div>
      <div>Content</div>
      <div>Content</div>
      <div>Content</div>
      <div>Content</div>
      <div>Content</div>
      <div>Content</div>
      <div>Content</div>
      <div>Content</div>
      <div>Content</div>    
      <div>Content</div>
      <div>Content</div>
      <div>Content</div>
      <div>Content</div>
      <div>Content</div>
      <div>Content</div>
      <div>Content</div>
      <div>Content</div>
      <div>Content</div>
      <div>Content</div> 
    </div>
<div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: scroll]

Comment: The start and end point of your scrollbar is determined by the size of your container.   You should provide a code snippet to better understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have updated question with a code block. I would like to change start point of scrollbar like picture.